# iframe www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed? google plus

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus, youtube-javascript-api

I saw this thread [Embed Youtube subscribe counter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200605/resolved-embed-youtube-subscribe-counter/) and I am wondering where does this button come from ?

I asked it on that thread but I don't think anyone noticed that

I tried some code for myself but this gives a js error Uncaught Error: Bad hint

```
<iframe data-gapiattached="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?bsv&amp;usegapi=1&amp;channel=HERE CHANNELNAME"
  style="overflow: hidden; height: 24px; width: 170px; border: 0;">
</iframe>
```

It looks like a plusone.js button but nothing to find.

[image]

Hope someone can shine some light on this youtube channel subscribe button :-)

only change this - channel=HERE CHANNELNAME

**UPDATE:**

Above is not the right embed code. It is a part of the plusone.js code from google
The right embed code is:

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="CHANNELNAME"></div>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

This works but still no documentation found so if anyone knows where to find the official code please let me know

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button